# Get values from a temporary table variable in DAX

Tags: dax, lookup-tables

Below is a piece of the fact table 'fTrans' that provides context to my question.

| Ticker | Date | Sale date related to respective purchase | Days | Transaction | Shares | Price | Purchase total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABEV3 | 01/Mar/2021 | 04/Jun/2021 | 95 | Purchase | 77 | $12.93 | $995.61 |
| ABEV3 | 04/May/2021 | 04/Jun/2021 | 31 | Purchase | 73 | $13.60 | $992.80 |
| ABEV3 | 04/Jun/2021 |  |  | Sale | 150 | $17.91 |  |
| ABEV3 | 28/Jun/2021 | 29/Oct/2021 | 123 | Purchase | 62 | $16.01 | $992.62 |
| ABEV3 | 29/Oct/2021 |  |  | Sale | 62 | $15.62 |  |
| ALSO3 | 07/Jan/2021 | 03/Feb/2021 | 27 | Purchase | 39 | $25.12 | $979.68 |
| ALSO3 | 03/Feb/2021 |  |  | Sale | 39 | $27.20 |  |
| ALSO3 | 29/Jun/2021 | 30/Mar/2022 | 274 | Purchase | 36 | $27.53 | $991.08 |
| ALSO3 | 07/Jan/2022 | 30/Mar/2022 | 82 | Purchase | 56 | $17.85 | $999.60 |
| ALSO3 | 30/Mar/2022 |  |  | Sale | 92 | $22.61 |  |
| APER3 | 18/Nov/2021 | 22/Dec/2021 | 34 | Purchase | 33 | $29.88 | $986.04 |
| APER3 | 22/Dec/2021 |  |  | Sale | 33 | $33.40 |  |
| APER3 | 14/Jun/2022 | 11/Aug/2022 | 58 | Purchase | 34 | $29.14 | $990.76 |
| APER3 | 04/Aug/2022 | 11/Aug/2022 | 7 | Purchase | 42 | $23.57 | $989.94 |
| APER3 | 11/Aug/2022 |  |  | Sale | 76 | $30.33 |  |

As you can see for all rows whose [Transaction] column is a "Sale" the [Days] column has empty values.

The reason being that there are cases where a "Sale" transaction relates to more than one previous "Purchase" transaction, therefore a weighted average of [Days] needs to be calculated for those "Sale" rows.

So, **my goal is to write up a measure that will provide a weighted average of [Days] for every [Transaction] "Sale" rows that are currently sitting empty**, and in order to get there I started with this:

```
EVALUATE
VAR Supp_Tbl = 
    ADDCOLUMNS( 
        SUMMARIZE( 
            fTrans, 
            fTrans[Ticker], 
            fTrans[Date], 
            fTrans[Sale date related to respective purchase], 
            fTrans[Transaction], 
            "@Days", SUMX( 
                fTrans, 
                IF( 
                    fTrans[Transaction] = "Sale", 
                    BLANK(), 
                    INT( fTrans[Sale date related to respective purchase] - fTrans[Date] ) 
                ) 
            ), 
            "@PurchTotal", [Purchase total] 
        ), 
        "@WghtProdDaysPurch", [@Days] * [@PurchTotal] 
    )
VAR Days_Tbl = 
    ADDCOLUMNS( 
        GROUPBY( 
            Supp_Tbl, 
            fTrans[Ticker], 
            fTrans[Sale date related to respective purchase], 
            "@SumPurchTotal", SUMX( 
                CURRENTGROUP(), 
                [@PurchTotal] 
            ), 
            "@SumWghtProdDaysPurch", SUMX( 
                CURRENTGROUP(), 
                [@WghtProdDaysPurch] 
            ) 
        ), 
        "@WghtdAvgDays", INT( 
                DIVIDE( 
                [@SumWghtProdDaysPurch], 
                [@SumPurchTotal] 
            ) 
        ) 
    )
RETURN
Days_Tbl
```

And it returns the following temporary table VAR "Days_Tbl" whose highlighted [@WghtdAvgDays] provides said weighted average of [Days] that I need for those "Sale" transaction rows:

| Ticker | Sale date related to respective purchase | @SumPurchTotal | @SumWghtProdDaysPurch | @WghtdAvgDays |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABEV3 |  |  |  |  |
| ABEV3 | 6/4/2021 | 1988.41 | 125359.75 | **63** |
| ABEV3 | 10/29/2021 | 992.62 | 122092.26 | **123** |
| ALSO3 |  |  |  |  |
| ALSO3 | 2/3/2021 | 979.68 | 26451.36 | **27** |
| ALSO3 | 3/30/2022 | 1990.68 | 353523.12 | **177** |
| APER3 |  |  |  |  |
| APER3 | 12/22/2021 | 986.04 | 33525.36 | **34** |
| APER3 | 8/11/2022 | 1980.7 | 64393.66 | **32** |

Now all I need is to get those values from [@WghtdAvgDays] under VAR "Days_Tbl" whenever [Sale date related to respective purchase] matches fTrans[Date] under each [Ticker].

And for that I first tried this:

```
LOOKUPVALUE( 
    [@WghtdAvgDays], 
    fTrans[Sale date related to respective purchase], 
    MAXX( 
        FILTER( 
            fTrans, 
            fTrans[Ticker] = EARLIER( fTrans[Ticker] ) && 
            fTrans[Date] = EARLIER( fTrans[Date] ) && 
            fTrans[Transaction] = "Sale" 
        ), 
        fTrans[Date] 
    ) 
)
```

But it right off the bat presents two issues:

1. The column fTransacoes[Data da venda relacionada à respectiva compra] either doesn't exist or doesn't have a relationship to any table available in the current context (message given by PBI when committing the measure code).
2. [@WghtdAvgDays] can't be used as the first argument of LOOKUPVALUE as it expects a fully qualified column (message provided by DAX Studio while attempting to troubleshoot the code).

**How am I supposed to get the values from the [@WghtdAvgDays] column under the temporary table VAR "Days_Tbl" then?**

Thanks in advance...

***P.S.:***
I also tried the route of creating a third temp table with SUMMARIZECOLUMNS but it ends up aggregating the overall total of [Days] for all rows:

```
FILTER( 
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS( 
        fTrans[Ticker], 
        fTrans[Date], 
        fTrans[Transaction], 
        "@Days", CALCULATE( 
            SUMX( 
                Days_Tbl, 
                [@WghtdAvgDays] 
            ), 
        fTrans[Sale date related to respective purchase] = fTrans[Date] 
        ) 
    ), 
    fTrans[Transaction] = "Sale" 
)
```

| Ticker | Date | Transaction | @Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABEV3 | 6/4/2021 | Sale | **30080** |
| ABEV3 | 10/29/2021 | Sale | **30080** |
| ALSO3 | 2/3/2021 | Sale | **30080** |
| ALSO3 | 3/30/2022 | Sale | **30080** |
| APER3 | 12/22/2021 | Sale | **30080** |
| APER3 | 8/11/2022 | Sale | **30080** |

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76941551/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With an input from an user in another forum and a couple of tweaks from his proposed code I was able to reach a calculated table that did the trick..

```
Table = 
    ADDCOLUMNS( 
        SUMMARIZE( 
            FILTER( 
                fTrans, 
                fTrans[Transaction] = "Sale" 
            ), 
            fTrans[Ticker],
            fTrans[Date] 
        ), 
        "WavgDays", 
        VAR Ticker_Ref = [Ticker]
        VAR Date_Ref = [Date]
        RETURN
            CALCULATE( 
                SUMX( fTrans,
                    DIVIDE( 
                        [Days] * [Purchase total], 
                        CALCULATE( 
                                [Purchase total], 
                            ALL( fTrans ), 
                            fTrans[Ticker] = Ticker_Ref, 
                            fTrans[Sale date related to respective purchase] = Date_Ref 
                        )
                    )
                ), 
                ALL( fTrans ), 
                fTrans[Ticker] = Ticker_Ref, 
                fTrans[Sale date related to respective purchase] = Date_Ref 
            ) 
        )
```